# java auto correct pattern-matcher - which item is the most similar in a given set?

Tags: parsing, pattern-matching, string-parsing

I was wondering how to implement the following problem: Say I have a 'set' of Strings and I wish to know which one is the most related to a given value.

Example:

```
String value= "ABBCCE";
```

Set contains: `{"JJKKLL", "ABBCC", "AAPPFFEE", "AABBCCDD", "ABBCEE", "AABBCCEE"}`

By 'most related' I assume there could be many options (valid one can be the last 2), but at least we can ignore some items (`JJKKLLL`).

What should be the approach to solve this kind of a problem (that at minmum, a result like `AABBCCEE` would be acceptable)

Any java code would be appreciated :-)

Comment: This is more a language-agnostic algorithm question, so I've removed the Java tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your "target" string (e.g. "ABBCCE") and each element in your set. Pick a maximum threshold above which you will consider items to be unrelated (in your example here, a threshold of one or two perhaps), and reject everything in the set that has a Levenshtein Distance greater than that from the target string.

An example implementation of the Levenshtein Distance computation in Java can be found [here](http://www.merriampark.com/ld.htm).

Comment: Thank you, I will follow up on this. I surely learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_Distance) metric, which measures similarities between two strings, including insertions and removals.